# RxAndroid ViewObservable NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java, rx-android

I have a `Button` from which I create an `Observable<OnClickEvent>`.

When the button is clicked, I wish to fetch a file from the network, but I run into issues regarding networking and threads.

This example throws `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` :

```
Observable<OnClickEvent> networkButtonObservable = ViewObservable.clicks(testNetworkButton);
networkButtonObservable
    .map(new Func1<OnClickEvent, List<String>>() {
             @Override
             public List<String> call(OnClickEvent onClickEvent) {
                 return TestAPI.getTestService().fetchTestResponse();
             }
         }
    )
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Action1<Object>() {
                   @Override
                   public void call(Object o) {Log.w("Final result: " + o);
                   }
               }
    );
```

So I try from another thread.

The following throws `rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Observers must subscribe from the main UI thread, but was Thread[RxNewThreadScheduler-1,5,main]` :

```
networkButtonObservable
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .map(new Func1<OnClickEvent, List<String>>() {
             @Override
             public List<String> call(OnClickEvent onClickEvent) {
                 return TestAPI.getTestService().fetchTestResponse();
             }
         }
    )
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Action1<Object>() {
                   @Override
                   public void call(Object o) {Log.w("Final result: " + o);
                   }
               }
    );
```

Ok.. Now I try with a `.debounce()` at the start :

```
networkButtonObservable
    .debounce(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .map(new Func1<OnClickEvent, List<String>>() {
             @Override
             public List<String> call(OnClickEvent onClickEvent) {
                 return TestAPI.getTestService().fetchTestResponse();
             }
         }
    )
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Action1<Object>() {
                   @Override
                   public void call(Object o) {Log.w("Final result: " + o);
                   }
               }
    );
```

And this succeeds.

Obviously I do not like to add delays to my code, so I am trying to figure out what's going on, thread-wise. Why is the first example not also executing the code inside the `.map()` in a background thread?

Or what am I missing here?

**--- Update**

I change my TestAPI to return an Observable, and change the first call to the networkButtonObservable to `.flatMap()`. This also functions properly. But I still don't know why the original way using `.map()` should fail.

```
networkButtonObservable
    .flatMap(new Func1<OnClickEvent, Observable<?>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<?> call(OnClickEvent onClickEvent) {
            return TestAPI.getTestService().fetchTestResponseObservable();
        }
    })
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Action1<Object>() {
                   @Override
                   public void call(Object o) {Log.w("Final result: " + o);
                   }
               }
    );
```

Comment: Like the error says, you can't run a Network operation in the UI Thread.

Comment: Which line throw this exception : `Observers must subscribe from the main UI thread, but was ...` ? I think that you subscribe to your Observable in another thread that the UI thread. (But I'm not shure)

Comment: `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` must go after your map, as the function in map is called when subscribing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not an expert in Android but based on the error messages, I think you need to bounce the value between the main thread and the background thread. Usually, Android examples show you to add a `subscribeOn`/`observeOn` pair to your stream processing:

```
Observable.just(1)
.map(v -> doBackgroundWork())
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(v -> {});
```

but in these cases, the 'source' is usually a cold observable you are in control.

In your question, the source is a hot `Observable` with specific requirements that you need to subscribe on the main thread, yet you need to do a network call on a background thread and then show the results on the main thread.

In this case, you can use `observeOn` multiple times:

```
networkButtonObservable
.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // just in case
.observeOn(Schedulers.io())
.map(v -> TestAPI.getTestService().fetchTestResponse())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(v -> updateGUI(v));
```

I think `fetchTestResponseObservable` has its own `subscribeOn` or `observeOn` applied to it so it doesn't throw the network exception.

Also I'd like to mention that using multiple `subscribeOn` is functionally equivalent to using only one that is closest to the emitting source, but technically it will hog unused threading resources. Using multiple `observeOn` in a stream, however, has relevance because you can meaningfully 'pipeline' the stream processing between threads with them.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think I understand how Rx works internally a bit better now.